# API for Java to rename/move files based on rulesets

Tags: java, io, rule-engine

I'm looking for an API to move/copy and rename files based on rulesets. Is there a better way than using only java.io and regexp?

Background: I want to write a small program to convert files (images) between different similar tools, but they all have different folder structures and different filenaming rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant knows to do this very well. Why not to write a task for ant that does what you want and use Ant filter for file filtering? Take a look on http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/filter.html

Comment: Good idea. This can be a very simple approach to solve the problem. I will read into it and decide, if it helps me in this case.